# Swift3 compile error

Tags: swift3

I'm a student studying Swift3.I'm currently making a calculator with Swift3, but I'm leaving a question and asking questions.
Please inform me why there is an error in the area and how to resolve it.
error message : Missing argument for parameter #2 in call
part : 20th line

```
import Foundation

func multiply(op1 :Double, op2: Double) -> Double {
    return op1 * op2
}

class CalculatorBrain {

    private var accumulator = 0.0

    func setOperand(operand: Double) {
        accumulator = operand
    }

    var operations: Dictionary<String, Operation> = [
        "π": Operation.Constant(M_PI),
        "e": Operation.Constant(M_E),
        "√": Operation.UnaryOperation(sqrt),
        "cos": Operation.UnaryOperation(cos),
        "×": Operation.BinaryOperation(multiply),
        "=": Operation.Equals
    ]

    enum Operation {
        case Constant(Double)
        case UnaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
        case BinaryOperation((Double), (Double) -> Double)
        case Equals
    }

    func performOperation(symbol: String) {
        if let operation = operations[symbol]{
            switch operation {
            case.Constant(let value): accumulator = value
            case.UnaryOperation(let function): accumulator = function(accumulator)
        case.BinaryOperation(let function): pending = PendingBinaryOperationInfo(binaryFunction: function, firstOperand:     accumulator)
            case.Equals:
                if pending != nil {
                    accumulator = pending!.binaryFunction(pending!.firstOperand, accumulator)
                    pending = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var pending: PendingBinaryOperationInfo?

    struct PendingBinaryOperationInfo {
        var binaryFunction: (Double, Double) -> Double
        var firstOperand: Double
    }

    var result: Double {
            get {
                return accumulator
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's the context, but you probably want to change

```
enum Operation {
    case Constant(Double)
    case UnaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation((Double), (Double) -> Double)
    case Equals
}
```

to

```
enum Operation {
    case Constant(Double)
    case UnaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
    case BinaryOperation((Double, Double) -> Double) // see change on this line
    case Equals
}
```